# cant print Captcah array

Tags: javascript, html

can help me to print that captcah on the new page html
i allready to link my javascrip.js to my index.html

```
 function autoCaptcah() // munculkan Captcah
{
        var temp1 = new Array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
        var temp2 = new Array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0');

    //do looping for the captcah
    for(var i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        var huruf1  = temp1[Math.floor(Math.random()*temp1.length)];
        var huruf2  = temp1[Math.floor(Math.random()*temp1.length)];
        var angka1  = temp2[Math.floor(Math.random()*temp2.length)];
        var angka2  = temp2[Math.floor(Math.random()*temp2.length)];
        var angka3  = temp2[Math.floor(Math.random()*temp2.length)];
        var captcah = huruf1+huruf2+angka1+angka2+angka3;
        document.getElementById("commandCaptcah").value = captcah;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <script>
        function autoCaptcah() // munculkan Captcah
        {

            var temp1 = new Array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
            var temp2 = new Array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0');

            //do looping for the captcah
            for(var i = 0; i<5; i++)
            {
                var huruf1  = temp1[Math.floor(Math.random()*temp1.length)];
                var huruf2  = temp1[Math.floor(Math.random()*temp1.length)];
                var angka1  = temp2[Math.floor(Math.random()*temp2.length)];
                var angka2  = temp2[Math.floor(Math.random()*temp2.length)];
                var angka3  = temp2[Math.floor(Math.random()*temp2.length)];
                var captcah = huruf1+huruf2+angka1+angka2+angka3;
                document.getElementById("commandCaptcah"+i).innerHTML = captcah;
            }

        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <div>
        <span id="commandCaptcah0"></span><br>
        <span id="commandCaptcah1"></span><br>
        <span id="commandCaptcah2"></span><br>
        <span id="commandCaptcah3"></span><br>
        <span id="commandCaptcah4"></span><br>
        <input type="submit" onclick="javascript:autoCaptcah()"/>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

i hope help you

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
         <head>
             <script type="text/javascript">
                 function Captcha(){
                     var temp1 = new Array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');
                     var temp2 = new Array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0');
                     var i;
                     for (i=0;i<6;i++){
                       var a = temp1[Math.floor(Math.random() * temp1.length)];
                       var b = temp1[Math.floor(Math.random() * temp1.length)];
                       var c = temp2[Math.floor(Math.random() * temp2.length)];
                       var d = temp2[Math.floor(Math.random() * temp2.length)];
                       var e = temp2[Math.floor(Math.random() * temp2.length)];
                      }
                    var code = a + b + c + d + e ;
                    document.getElementById("mainCaptcha").value = code
                  }
                  function ValidCaptcha(){
                      var string1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('mainCaptcha').value);
                      var string2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);
                      if (string1 == string2){
                        return true;
                      }
                      else{        
                        return false;
                      }
                  }
                  function removeSpaces(string){
                    return string.split(' ').join('');
                  }
             </script>    
        </head>
     <body onload="Captcha();">
        <table>
          <tr>
           <td>
                 Text Captcha<br />
           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>
             <input type="text" id="mainCaptcha"/>
              <input type="button" id="refresh" value="Refresh" onclick="Captcha();" />
           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtInput"/>    
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>
            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Check" onclick="alert(ValidCaptcha());"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
 </html>
```